# Get Woocommerce Variation Parent Attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

I have a Woocommerce variable product.  I need to get the attribute (pa_brand) of the parent of that variation?  Here is the code I have which is not returning anything.  How can I get a product variation from a product id?

```
global $product;
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_id );
$brand = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_brand' );
```

Comment: Where are you using this code? You need to update your question adding a context first.

Comment: I am using this code in a function that is being used to create a Google product feed.

Comment: I found the answer: 

$product = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() );
$brand = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_brand' );

Comment: @RobGelhausen, post it as an answer and accept it. It's not just about getting points, but it's also easier for others to notice than a comment.

Answer (score 20):

@Rob Gelhausen already answered it as a comment for the question. To get more notice, I'm making it as an answer.

To get Main product ID / Parent product from variation product id, we can use below code.

```
$variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
$product = wc_get_product( $variation->get_parent_id() );
```

To get attribute, we can use below code.

```
$brand = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_brand' );
```